# Computing Maximum Agreement Subtree of two unrooted phylogenetic trees with PhyloNet?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny

I am using PhyloNet to compute the MAST of two unrooted binary phylogenetic trees but I am not getting the output that I should. I think the issue might be with the way I am writing the trees in the input, but  I don't know.

For example: if I input `T1=((((1,5),6), (2,4)),3)` and `T2=((1,2), (((3,5),6),4))`, the MAST returned is `((1,2),3)`, whereas if I draw the trees, I get the MAST `((3,6),(4,2))`.

I think this might happen because somehow it assumes a root, but I have no idea how to fix it or if that is really the issue. Any guidelines for computing MASTs of unrooted trees are appreciated.